# Socat replicate to multiple sources

Tags: networking, server

So, I have an input address, such as udp://0.0.0.0:1234 and I want to replicate this address to two other diffrente hosts.

Something like:

```
socat UDP4-RECVFROM:12345,fork,ip-ttl=4,reuseaddr UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.200.48:12345,fork UDP-DATAGRAM:192.168.200.48:12346
```

I know the command above wont work, but I hope it explains what I want to do.

I want to get one source and replicate it to two different hosts.

Is that possible? Thanks;